# Button moves when zooming image. Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could anyone please help me. When I zoom an image button changes its position. Do not know how to heal it..  I assume that might be because they are under "ScrollView" but when I add buttons to "View" they don't respond, they only respond in "ScrollView".

***.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UIButton *addImageBtn;   
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *addImageBtn;
```

***.m**

```
@synthesize addImageBtn;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have`ivars` for your `addImageBtn` and `imageView`? Why not just have the properties (`@property`) for them as this auto generates the `ivars` so you actually have 2 ivars for `addImageBtn` one that you create and one that the property creates. Also you don't need the `@synthesize` any more as the getters and setters are also auto generated for you.

Comment: Add your buttons under your `UIView` not your `UIScrollView`. Do you have auto layout enabled? Also, @Popeye is correct. Do not create the `ivars` directly use `@property` instead.

Comment: @Popeye Thank you I've cleaned my code + added buttons as a subView - everything works perfect.

Answer (score -2):

Do you really need the buttons inside the scroll? Is autolayout on ? Attach the buttons to the bottom of the container view and put it outside the scroll

Comment: This seems more like a comment not an answer.